# Change range of age groups

Tags: r

I need to merge two databases with age groups categorized differently. I need to change age categories in one of the datasets. So my age groups in the data I want to modify are from five to five years ("0-4", "5-9", "10-14", "14-19"......"95-99" and "100 or more")

To mirror the age groups in the other dataset, I need the age groups in the middle to stay the same, and to change the ranges from the early and late ages, so it would be ("0-14", "15-29", "30-39" and then "95 and more"), -the other age groups would remain the same-.

I'm relatively new to R. I tried this, although long, I thought it would work, but it doesn't. It generates NAs in all age groups except 0-14.

```
pob<-pob %>% 
  mutate(
    # Create categories
    Edad1 = dplyr::case_when(
      Edad..grupos.quinquenales. == "0-4 años"  ~ "0-14",
      Edad..grupos.quinquenales. == "5-9 años"  ~ "0-14",
      Edad..grupos.quinquenales. == "10-14 años"  ~ "0-14",
      Edad..grupos.quinquenales. == "95-99 años"  ~ "95 y más años",
      Edad..grupos.quinquenales. == "100 años y más"  ~ "95 y más años",
      Edad..grupos.quinquenales. == "15-19 años"  ~ "15-29 años",
      Edad..grupos.quinquenales. == "20-24 años"  ~ "15-29 años",
      Edad..grupos.quinquenales. == "25-29 años"  ~ "15-29 años",
      Edad..grupos.quinquenales. == "30-34 años"  ~ "30-39 años",
      Edad..grupos.quinquenales. == "35-39 años"  ~ "30-39 años",
      Edad..grupos.quinquenales. == "40-44 años"  ~ "40-44 años",
      Edad..grupos.quinquenales. == "45-49 años"  ~ "45-49 años",
      Edad..grupos.quinquenales. == "50-54 años"  ~ "50-54 años",
      Edad..grupos.quinquenales. == "55-59 años"  ~ "55-59 años",
      Edad..grupos.quinquenales. == "60-64 años"  ~ "60-64 años",
      Edad..grupos.quinquenales. == "65-69 años"  ~ "65-69 años",
      Edad..grupos.quinquenales. == "70-74 años"  ~ "70-74 años",
      Edad..grupos.quinquenales. == "75-79 años"  ~ "75-79 años",
      Edad..grupos.quinquenales. == "80-84 años"  ~ "80-84 años",
      Edad..grupos.quinquenales. == "85-89 años"  ~ "85-89 años",
      Edad..grupos.quinquenales. == "90-94 años"  ~ "90-94 años",
    ),
    # Convert to factor
    Edad1 = factor(
      Edad1,
      level = c("0-14", "15-29","30-39", "40-44", "45-49", "50-54", "55-59", "60-64", "65-69", "70-74", "75-79", "80-84", "85,89", "90-94", "95 y más")
    )
  )
```

Thank you!

Comment: The data has to match the levels of a factor exactly, so `0-14` works because that's the value used in your `case_when()` condition.  The rest don't match because you suffixed them all with `años`.  So either remove `años` from your `case_when()` statement or add it to the `levels`.  Note that `forcats::fct_collapse()` is a convenience function designed to make this task easier.

Comment: `case_when` is usually used for very complex conditions. You just have a from -> to mapping. One can create a table `age_groups` with columns `Edad..grupos.quinquenales` and `age_group` to do `left_join(pob,age_groups)` to reduce the repetitive code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `setNames` to define the replacement pairs and `str_replace_all` to implement the replacements (request: next time please post **reproducible** data):

```
# define replacement pairs:
replacements <- setNames(c("0-14", "15-29"), # new strings
                         c("(0-4|5-9|10-14) años", "(15-19|20-24|25-29) años")) # old strings


# implement replacements:
library(stringr)
df %>%
  mutate(Edad1 = str_replace_all(Edad, replacements))
        Edad  Edad1
1   0-4 años   0-14
2   5-9 años   0-14
3 10-14 años   0-14
4 15-19 años  15-29
5 20-24 años  15-29
6 25-29 años  15-29
```

Data:

```
df <- data.frame(
  Edad = c("0-4 años", "5-9 años", "10-14 años", "15-19 años", "20-24 años", "25-29 años")
)
```